# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Number'

Tags: python-imaging-library

Not sure what is causing this...

I am running Python 3.4.3 using the "Pillow-3.3.0.win32-py34.exe" installation file.

Upon import Image with

```
from PIL import Image
```

I try to set "a.jpg" as my image using

```
img = Image.open("a.jpg")
```

However I get this error,

```
>>> img = Image.open("a.jpg")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 2289, in open
    preinit()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 365, in preinit
    from PIL import JpegImagePlugin
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\PIL\JpegImagePlugin.py", line 40, in <modu
le>
    from PIL import Image, ImageFile, TiffImagePlugin, _binary
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\PIL\TiffImagePlugin.py", line 50, in <modu
le>
    from fractions import Fraction
  File "C:\Python34\lib\fractions.py", line 6, in <module>
    from decimal import Decimal
  File "C:\Python34\lib\decimal.py", line 3855, in <module>
    _numbers.Number.register(Decimal)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Number'
```

Might not be related to Pillow, but would still really appreciate help!

Answer (score 20):

Is there a file called `numbers.py` in the current working directory?

That could be the reason of the problem, because it'd prevent the import of the standard library module [numbers](http://docs.python.org/2/library/numbers.html).

(Suggestion from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18045344/724176).)

Comment: Yes when you are learning you might create file named numbers.py